# Do cookies persist in Guest profile?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

I'm wondering if Google Chrome's Guest profile starts a new fresh profile with no cookies every time. As an experiment, I went to a website on medium.com which said I've reached my monthly allowance of articles and said "Read the rest of this story with a free account."

I then started a new session in Guest profile, and went to the same page. It still said "Read the rest of this story with a free account."

I then went to that page in Firefox, and was able to read the whole article.

So that seems to imply that Google's Guest account is not entirely anonymous but in fact saves some data between sessions. Is that true? I thought the Guest account didn't do that.

Comment: The guest account is not supposed to keep cookies. It might have been the website that was actually tracking your browser and perhaps your IP address.